# I want to convert String to Long. but I'm getting number format exception? how to correct this.?

Tags: jsf

this is my code
String userId="";
//The below line throws NumberFormatException in my jsf bean class. how to correct this...
Long uid=Long.parseLong(userId);

String userId=" ";

Long uid=Long.parseLong(userId);

this code is throwing fallowing error....
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Answer (score 0):

An empty string (`""`) is not a valid Long. A long must consist of one or more digits.

You first assign an empty String to `userId` and then try to parse it.

Comment: It is not empty String. it is getting value from ****.xhtml page. in JSF Bean class...............  and if i print the userId like this System.out.println(userId); it prints the userId what ever i am getting from ****.xhtml page.

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` means that you tried to parse an empty String.

Comment: Well, you edited your code. But it still assigns a non-number String to userId: `" "` is not a valid Long.

Comment: It is not empty String. it is getting value from ****.xhtml page. in JSF Bean class............... and if i print the userId like this System.out.println(userId); it prints the userId what ever i am getting from ****.xhtml page.

Comment: Show me the code and the error message if you want to get help. Nobody can help you if you post wrong code and a wrong error message.

Comment: ok, thank's for u r answer, i got the soultion where i am getting error.